# Validate the task C# works corrected

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, task

I'm trying to make a list of flights that search in various web services and returns for unusual flights. I have created a TASK and wish someone validate and give me tips to improve.

The Task waits up to 30 seconds. If something ocorer at some web services I want to return even though it gives the error.

Please see the code and evaluate:

The Task that return the flights

```
public List<datatypes.ResponseAvail> SearchRQWithTask(datatypes.RequestAvail rq)
    {

         List<datatypes.ResponseAvail> rsLst = new List<datatypes.ResponseAvail>();
         try
         { 
             var tasks = new List<Task>();

             foreach (var broker in rq.brokers)
             {
                 switch (broker.NomeBroker)
                 {
                     case Brokers.Azul:
                         brokers.Azul az = new brokers.Azul();
                         tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => rsLst.Add(az.SearchAzul(rq))));
                         break;
                     case Brokers.Sabre:
                         brokers.Sabre sabre = new brokers.Sabre();
                         tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => rsLst.Add(sabre.SearchSabre(rq))));
                         break;
                     case Brokers.TAM:
                         brokers.TAM tam = new brokers.TAM();
                         tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => rsLst.Add(tam.SearchTAM(rq))));
                         break;
                     default:
                         break;
                 }
             }
             Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray(), 10000);
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {                 
             rsLst[0].Error = ex;
         }

        return rsLst;
    }
```

The Request Avail

```
 public class RequestAvail
{

    public int idClienteRq { get; set; }       
    public List<BrokersList> brokers  { get; set; }
    public string origem { get; set; }
    public string destino { get; set; }
}
public class BrokersList
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public Brokers NomeBroker { get; set; }
}

public enum Brokers
{   
    Azul = 1,
    Sabre = 2,
    GOL = 3,
    TAM = 4             
}
```

The responseAvail

```
 public class ResponseAvail : Exception
{
    public int code { get; set; }
    public string brokerName { get; set; }
    public List<ListVoos> voos { get; set; }
    public Exception Error { get; set; }
}
public class ListVoos
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string ori { get; set; }
    public string des { get; set; }
    public DateTime departure { get; set; }
    public DateTime arrival { get; set; }

}
```

The brokers that I execute from web services call. This is a fake return.

```
class Azul
{        
    public datatypes.ResponseAvail SearchAzul(datatypes.RequestAvail rq)
    {
        datatypes.ResponseAvail rs = new datatypes.ResponseAvail();
        rs.brokerName = "AZUL";
        rs.code = 100;
        rs.voos = new List<datatypes.ListVoos>();
        rs.voos.Add(new datatypes.ListVoos{ 
            arrival = new DateTime(2013,05,10), 
            departure = new DateTime(2013,05,10),
            id = 1,
            ori="SAO",
            des="GIG"               
        });

        return rs;
    }


}
```

Sabre Broker

```
public class Sabre
{
    public datatypes.ResponseAvail SearchSabre(datatypes.RequestAvail rq)
    {
        datatypes.ResponseAvail rs = new datatypes.ResponseAvail();

        try
        {

        rs.brokerName = "Sabre";
        rs.code = 5665;
        rs.voos = new List<datatypes.ListVoos>();
        rs.voos.Add(new datatypes.ListVoos
        {
            arrival = new DateTime(2013, 05, 10),
            departure = new DateTime(2013, 05, 10),
            id = 1,
            ori = "SAO",
            des = "GIG"
        });

        Thread.Sleep(100);
        //
        //if (rs.voos[0].ori == "SAO")
        //{
        //    throw new Exception("Erro  no source Sabre....");

        //}

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }            

        return rs;
    }

}
```

Tam Broker fake

```
public class TAM
{
    public datatypes.ResponseAvail SearchTAM(datatypes.RequestAvail rq)
    {
        datatypes.ResponseAvail rs = new datatypes.ResponseAvail();
        rs.brokerName = "TAM";
        rs.code = 300;
        rs.voos = new List<datatypes.ListVoos>();
        rs.voos.Add(new datatypes.ListVoos
        {
            arrival = new DateTime(2013, 05, 10),
            departure = new DateTime(2013, 05, 10),
            id = 1,
            ori = "SAO",
            des = "GIG"
        });

        return rs;
    }

}
```

Comment: So your question is, will you please review this code for me? codereview.stackexchange.com works for that.

Comment: You could have at least made an attempt to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not necessarily work correctly.

Right now, you're using `List<T>` to store your results, but using the ThreadPool via `Task.Factory.StartNew` to generate them.  This is not going to be thread safe, which could cause problems if the results come back at the same time.

That being said, this code, in general, would benefit from using the new `async` and `await` language features, and running the operations as async operations.  This would avoid using the thread pool entirely, which will provide far more scalability.

Comment: Hi Reed, So what is the best approach? This code is used to return all flights until 30  seconds.
I would like to get the thread safe nad If ocurred some error I will stored the message. This application is used by one website. ps. I send one mail in you blog with the same question.

Comment: @Rodrigo As I said, look into using async and await - it'll be a much better, cleaner approach, and avoid the thread synchronization issues in this case.